# How to filter rows from a table based on "If at least one common value in list of string and a column that has list of string"

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-repositories

I have one string `students = "Ram,Jack,jim.. and so on";`

I have one table called `sports_group`  which is as below:

---

| Sport_id | name | school | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fb100 | Atul,Mani,Ram,Gopal | St. marry | Delhi |
| Cri101 | Jack,Marry,Kim | Gschool | Delhi |
| Bdm102 | Alex,Rex | NTschool | mumbai |

I have to list all the rows in which name column and students string have atleast one common value.
So Desired output should be:

```
{
    “Sport_id”:” Fb100”,
    “name”,” Atul,Mani,Ram,Gopal”,
    “school”,” St. marry”,
    “city”,” Delhi”
},

{
    “Sport_id”:” Cri101”,
    “name”,” Jack,Marry,Kim”,
    “school”,” Govt. school”,
    “city”,” Delhi”
}
```

What I am doing in my spring data repository class :

```
@Query(value = "select * from sports_group  g where FIND_IN_SET(?1, g.name)<>0  order by g.modifiedtime desc", nativeQuery = true)
Slice<SprtsGroup> searchByNames(String students, Pageable pageable);
```

But this is working  only if  String students has only one value e.g.:

```
 String students = “Ram”
```

But this is not working  only if  String students has more than one value e.g.:

```
 String students = “Ram,Kim”
```

Can anyone please help me how can I improve my native query to get desired result.
Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Note: there are similar threads exist but I could not reach to the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query to something like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM sports_group g WHERE EXISTS "
             + "(SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM sports_group) AS names "
             + "WHERE FIND_IN_SET(names.name, ?1) <> 0 AND FIND_IN_SET(names.name, g.name) <> 0) "
             + "ORDER BY g.modifiedtime DESC",
        nativeQuery = true)
```

This way your using the `FIND_IN_SET` method for each name

Comment: Thanks John but Its not working for String students = “Ram” but for  String students = “Ram,Kim” its returning empty[]. It should return   : {
    “Sport_id”:” Fb100”,
    “name”,” Atul,Mani,Ram,Gopal”,
    “school”,” St. marry”,
    “city”,” Delhi”
},

{
    “Sport_id”:” Cri101”,
    “name”,” Jack,Marry,Kim”,
    “school”,” Govt. school”,
    “city”,” Delhi”
}